# django integrity error, many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, referential-integrity, integrity, database-integrity

That's my models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.email)


class Link(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ShortURL')


class ShortURL(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    short_end = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    counter = models.IntegerField()
```

adding users works just fine:

```
>>> user = User.objects.create("john_doe@planetearth.com")
```

I get integrity error when I try to add link:

```
>>> link = Link.objects.create("stackoverflow.com")
IntegrityError: shortener_link.short_end may not be NULL
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a link like this:

```
Link.objects.create(link="stackoverflow.com", user = request.user, short_end = 'stack', counter = 0)
```

since all of those fields are required.

Comment: now I get another error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File ".../django/db/models/manager.py", line 137, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
    File ".../django/db/models/query.py", line 375, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
    File ".../django/db/models/base.py", line 367, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwargs.keys()[0])
    TypeError: 'counter' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: That error would imply that you don't have a counter field defined in models

Comment: Yes, but it is defined. In ShortURL class. I'm confused.

Comment: [link]https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/

the beatles example works, I'm a moron for not looking up documentation first.